# Solana Anchor: How to forward in time?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

During my Anchor tests, I need to simulate certain time change for my Solana program to react differently, such that the time_now below in my Solana program should change:

```
use solana_program::sysvar::clock::Clock;
let time_now = Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp;
```

can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This may not pertain to Anchor, but on the Rust side, it's possible to advance time forward using the `program-test` crate, creating your program test using `start_with_context()`, and then using `warp_to_slot()`.

Here's a simple example of advancing the clock on a program: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/c550b32a4489debb163cf6e6d170e934b0b4faaf/program-test/tests/warp.rs#L54