# How do I control the solana-test-validator clock in javascript?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I have program logic that depends on the `Clock` sysvar. In order to properly test my code I need to "fast-forward" the cluster beyond a certain point in time.

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69011563/solana-anchor-how-to-forward-in-time) that this is possible in Rust but I would like to be able to do this using javascript as I have a lot of js test code already + a very convenient javascript client to interact with my program.

There is the `---warp-slot` option on the `solana-test-validator` but that requires restarting the validator which isn't very convenient (I am using Anchor which manages the validator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunately not possible in JavaScript, as you discovered.  Your only option currently is to restart the validator with the `--warp-slot` argument, which is not very practical in a testing environment.

Side note: a PR for this behavior would be very appreciated!  You'd need to expose some endpoint to tell the validator to move forward, similar to the logic done for the program-test framework: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/dd15193c69f5292ff566b84837516097bc0b8f57/program-test/src/lib.rs#L1101

Comment: I'm trying to make this PR. Is it definitely possible to tell the validator to move forward from inside an RPC method? I've added a new method to the my local RPC but I'm not sure how to edit the validator sysvar from there.

Comment: To be honest, it isn't easy. You'll need to manipulate the banks inside the validator.  There's a working example doing this in `program-test`, but it isn't guaranteed that the same code will work in a full validator setting: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/7b6880f652eec427a442be8bc8f08fbcfb90ebf8/program-test/src/lib.rs#L1080